# openssl + random int for Token, problems when it comes to form action

Tags: php, antiforgerytoken

I have a Tokening function like this:

```
public static function create() {
        $int = random_int(8, 64);
        $ssl = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
        $base64 = base64_encode($ssl);
        return Session::put(Config::get('session/token_name'), trim($base64, '='));
    }
```

My tokening function is working, the problem occurs when I tried it now on multiple `forms` *Note: same page*

This is my form (example, I only changed the names but that's on my code):

```
<form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="t_sample1" value="<?php echo Token::make(); ?>">
            <button name="btn1">sample1</button>
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="t_sample2" value="<?php echo Token::make(); ?>">
            <button name="btn2">sample2</button>
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="t_sample3" value="<?php echo Token::make(); ?>">
            <button name="btn3">sample3</button>
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="t_sample4" value="<?php echo Token::make(); ?>">
            <button name="btn4">sample4</button>
        </form>
```

Then, I am only trying this tokening style because I changed my Tokening function from `md5(uniqid())` style because they said it is not safe and I read alot of expert tips and said go for `openssl` then `base64_encode` it. This is the `php` code for determining if what form is clicked.

```
if(Input::exists()) {
if(Token::check(Input::get('t_sample1'))) {
    $echo = 'sample1';
}
if(Token::check(Input::get('t_sample2'))) {
    $echo = 'sample2';
}
if(Token::check(Input::get('t_sample3'))) {
    $echo = 'sample3';
}
if(Token::check(Input::get('t_sample4'))) {
    $echo = 'sample4';
}
```

}

Now the problem is, when I try to click the button **sample1-sample3** my `token::check` is false, **but** only sample4 does `token::check` go true. It seems that only the last `form` will only have a correct `token`. So I am looking for help how to figure it out how to make the other sample(1-3) go true under `token::check`, btw the `md5(uniqid())` tokening function is working.